# how to select multiple columns in r when max()>=1

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
y=data.frame( rv1=c(0,1,0,0,0), rv2=c(0,0,0,0,0), rv3=c(0,0,0,0,0), rv4=c(0,0,0,0,1), rv5=c(0,0,3,1,0))
```

Data structure:

```
  rv1 rv2 rv3 rv4 rv5
1   0   0   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   3
4   0   0   0   0   1
5   0   0   0   1   0
```

I would like to select columns where `max()>1`

Expected output:

```
   rv1 rv4 rv5
1   0   0   0
2   1   0   0
3   0   0   3
4   0   0   1
5   0   1   0
```

Sample code:

```
y %>% 
colSums()>=1 %>%
```

Output:

```
rv1   rv2   rv3   rv4   rv5 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `select` with a logical expression constructed within `where` using `max` and `>=`

```
library(dplyr)
y %>% 
    select(where(~ max(.) >= 1))
```

-output

```
  rv1 rv4 rv5
1   0   0   0
2   1   0   0
3   0   0   3
4   0   0   1
5   0   1   0
```

---

Or use `colMaxs` from `matrixStats` to create the logical vector

```
library(matrixStats)
y[colMaxs(as.matrix(y)) >=1]
```

---

Or using `base R` by looping over the columns with `sapply/lapply` or using `apply` with `MARGIN = 2` to construct the logical vector

```
y[sapply(y, max) >= 1]
```

Comment: @krun, what is the function of the "~" in ~max() ?

Comment: @cnauber it is a lambda function concise syntax (`function(x) max(x)`) the `~ max(.x)` in tidyverse